# What is a terminal disease that a 17 year old could die from but wouldn't have to be in the hospital for?

Tags: death

Im writing a story where two teens run off to enjoy life together for the last two months of one of their lives. I need to find a terminal illness that would work for this, to where the character can still move in the begginning and would  die even with treatment. Its okay if he would have a wheelchair towards the end, or suffer with mental instability towards the end too (like forgetting,  hallucinations, etc.). Does anyone know of any diseases that would fit this criteria?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid questions about what to write are off-topic here.

Comment: All of them, getting a terminal diagnosis does not mean you have to spend your last days in hospital. The real question is what level of medical help can the character afford, will they lay in bed with their partner taking care of them? or pay for a private nurse while the partner sits holding their hand? Your character chooses to live the way you want them to. It is more about at what point does the healthy partner decide that they can't do this any more.

Comment: Go to worldbuilding.stackexchange.com - that's the right place for a question like this.

Comment: Generally, terminal diseae means you are not going to get better (but we can help offset the pain) and on some such ocasions, hospice care is perscribed (basically a nurse makes the rounds to hospice patients at their home to do nurse things like give meds or help with some simple tasks and make sure they're still alive, and notify people if not).   You can still live for a while while being in hospice care, but the point is there's nothing that the hospital can do for you that requires you being held in a bed there.

Answer (score 2):

Cancer!

And even though I'm going to get cursed and down-voted (again). John Green's "The Fault in our Stars" was a #1 Best-seller in 2012 and the movie made over $300,000,000.00 in 2014. Guess what it's about?

If you really want to be a writer or a story-teller? Know what's out there. You can't really be a rocket scientist without knowing a little bit about rockets, and maybe even science?

There a gazillion stories about romances between terminal teens. Read the plots.

https://nypost.com/2019/01/31/enough-with-heart-tugging-films-about-quirky-terminally-ill-teens/